# Prove or show that $\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}|1<x<4\}.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider for each $n\in \mathbb{N} \setminus\{0\}$,  the set
$$A_{n}=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}\ |\ 1<x\leqslant4-\frac{1}{n}\}.$$

Prove or show that

$$\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}\ |\ 1<x<4\}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first inclusion take $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ so that $1<x<4$, and sufficiently large $n$ so that $\frac{1}{4-x}\leq n$. From here it is a simple matter to show that $x\in A_n$, and is therefore also in the infinite union. The second inclusion is trivial as each set $A_n$ is a subset of $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}|1<x<4\}$.